# Identifying AppleEvents in main message loop

Tags: objective-c, events, message-queue, appleevents

I have a main message loop. I'm looking for a way to check if the event is an AppleEvent and if it's Event Class is of 'MyClass' then do something.
I've looked in NSEvent reference and was lost not finding what i need.
Please can someone suggest an approach?

```
while (!shutdown_now_) 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSEvent *event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];

        //if event is AppleEvent AND event class is <MyEventClass> then do something

        if (event) [NSApp sendEvent:event];
        [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get an Apple Event via `NSEvent` in your loop like that.

Because `NSEvent` just doesn't cover it.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventObjectsTypes/EventObjectsTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH4-SW4) says

> Almost all events in a Cocoa application are represented by objects of
>   the NSEvent class. (**Exceptions include Apple events, notifications,
>   and similar items.**) Each NSEvent object more narrowly represents a
>   particular type of event, each with its own requirements for handling.
>   The following sections describe the characteristics of an NSEvent
>   object and the possible event types

You can find some more information in `NSApplication` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html)

---

Instead you can use the `NSAppleEventManager` class to register your own Apple event handlers with following [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleEventManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAppleEventManager/setEventHandler:andSelector:forEventClass:andEventID:)

```
- (void)setEventHandler:(id)handler
            andSelector:(SEL)handleEventSelector
          forEventClass:(AEEventClass)eventClass
             andEventID:(AEEventID)eventID
```

Comment: AppleEvents like other Events dispatched from the message queue. If the Event is Apple Event, it is being sent to AppleEvent Manager, who is looking in the dispatch table and calls the registered handler. I know how to register handlers and it works for me.

Comment: Apple events are exceptions from what `NSEvent` covers. Check the updated answer

Comment: I've debugged the loop. AppleEvents are being redirected to AppleEvent Manager from  nextEventMatchingMask

Comment: `nextEventMatchingMask` returns `NSEvent *` which DOES NOT cover AppleEvents ! have you checked the links in my answer ?

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do now. Your question has been answered - its not possible to do through `NSEvent` and the only way is to register your callbacks explicitely